# GridView Initialization Using findViewById Crashing My App, but ALL Other Code Runs?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

So I have almost completed this app I just wanted to add a GridView into it that has 9 columns, 3 rows, and does some stuff with it. However, when I went to assign Gridview gridView to my ID in XML, it crashed. There was NO other code related to the grid, and when I remove the line, the app starts. Within the XML, I am SURE the ID exists. As an example, I put in a test, EditText dataEdt1. The dataEdt1 works, meaning that the XML file is read, and the ID should be visible.  Here is the Java, followed by the XML.

```
public class Auto extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener{//, GridView.OnItemClickListener{
public Auto() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    public static Auto newInstance() {
        Auto fragment = new Auto();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();

        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }
    Context context;
    EditText dataEdt1;
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        TransitionInflater inflater = TransitionInflater.from(requireContext());
        setExitTransition(inflater.inflateTransition(R.transition.fade_f));
        setEnterTransition(inflater.inflateTransition(R.transition.slide_right_f));
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // THIS IS THE PROBLEM METHOD
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_auto, container,false);
        context = container.getContext();
        dataEdt1 = root.findViewById(R.id.textComment);
        GridView gridView = root.findViewById(R.id.gridView1); //THIS LINE CRASHES THE APP, but it does not have a Gradle build error. 
        /*
        the code I want to add once this GridView is being detected.
        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
                if (getBackgroundColor(v) == Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF")){
                    v.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));
                    gridQR.set(position, 0);

                }else{
                    v.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
                    gridQR.set(position, 1);

                }
            }

        });
         */
        
        dataEdt1.setOnClickListener(this); //As an example, I did this code, which works. 
        dataEdt1.setText(MainActivity.getAutoC());
        return root;
    }
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.textComment:
                dataEdt1.setText("");
                break;
        }
    }
```

Here's the XML

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/cardview_dark_background"
    tools:context=".Auto">
  <EditText
            android:id="@+id/textComment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:autofillHints=""
            android:hint="Comments about Auto"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:textSize="26dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />
<GridLayout
            android:id="@+id/gridView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:columnCount="9"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:rowCount="3"
            app:layout_constraintWidth="match_constraint"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textComment"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/gridHeader3"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView"
            tools:context=".GridXMLActivity">
</FrameLayout>
```

I have tried to run the code without the line about finding the view by ID. This works. However, the second I set GridView to the root.findViewById(R.id.gridView1);, it crashes. There's nothing else I've tried, I'm stumped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replicated your code and this is what the issue is
`android.widget.GridLayout` cannot be cast to `android.widget.GridView`

I think you need to change the Gridlayout to GridView in the xml.